# github push, drive me nuts

Tags: git, github

All I did is fork someone's repo and clone it to my local git file.it only contains readme and the other .R file. I modify the .R file, and saved it. I open my terminal, and cd into my git file, and type "git commit -m "initial comment""   and type "git push origin master"
the error message is blowing.  " failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/*****/****'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind" blah..blah,,

Could please just show me a step by step guid that can make the git push work?  thanks

Comment: Do you understand the error message?

Comment: @FelixKling  Although not the OP, I do not understand it and would be happy to read and upvote any answer that included a little explanation!

Comment: don't really understand, it's one of the hint messages, other hints are int: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details

Comment: Did you run `git push --help` and read it? All those hints tell you what you have to do to push: you need to pull in the remote changes first before you can push your changes. If you are new to git you may want to read http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 first.

Comment: Read the hints *closely* and the follow the instructions when they are provided and more often than not, the problem will get resolved.  This has been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the problem here is that your local repo is one or more commits behind whatever the origin is, and the changes that you made conflict with the changes made in the master since you cloned it. Here is a diagram that may help:

```
Time:      T+0        T+1        T+2   T+3                  T+5 (now)
Original:  v.0 -------(clone)----------(change made - v.1)--|--->
Your Copy:            \--(v.0)---(change made)--------------|--->
```

If you were to merge your change back to the origin, you'd overwrite changes to the file you modified, thus, git doesn't let you do that. The correct procedure is to commit the changes locally (which you have done) then do a git pull (to pull in the changes made at T+3 in my diagram above), resolve any conflicts locally, commit the merge, then push your commit to the origin.

For what it's worth, git is *much* easier with a visual client. In Windows I'd recommend TortoiseGit.

Comment: that sounds promising. Could you please provide specific command for pull,commit and push? Sorry I am a newbe for git hub. Appreciate.

Comment: The command was given by the hint you ignored. It is: "git push"